# Print values in a different column header of values in lists

Tags: python, pandas, csv, datetime

This code is used to track which delivery's were late. I wish to find every instance of a late delivery and find the purchase order number associated with it. My current code is able to produce a list that shows the number of days late for a specified range. However, because the values are stored in a list, I am unable to find which purchase order number is associated with the late days. I wish print in the terminal, the purchase order number, and the number of days late the delivery was. ( From there I will use an if statement to only see values > 0 to see only which deliveries were late ). My question is, how do i print in the terminal, the purchase order number with the number of days late it was next to it( I do not know how to do this as all the values of " numbers of days late" are stored in the list)

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
import datetime


def calculate(number):   
    fileread = pd.read_csv('otd.csv', encoding='latin-1')
    Deliveryvalue = fileread['Delivery Date']
    Desiredvalue = fileread['source desired delivery date']



    date_format = '%m/%d/%Y'

    date1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(Deliveryvalue[number], date_format)
    date2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(Desiredvalue[number], date_format)

    diff= date1 - date2
    diff2 = diff.days



    return diff2

list = [] 
for i in range(1,20):
    list.append(calculate(i))

for y in list: 
    if y > 1:
        print(list)
```

prints this:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -7, 3, 50, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, -9, 0]
# the negative numbers are early deliveries
```

Here is a dummy example of my csv file:

[image]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: It'd be nice if you can elaborate a bit more with what you exactly are asking for.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, because all of my values are in a list, for the amount of days late the deliveries are, I want to be able to cleanly print in the terminal the numbers of days late and a purchase order number next to it. ( from there I would make an if statement that only shows values greater than 0 to see only late deliveries)

Comment: @JosephSeungJaeDollar I have updated my question a bit, hope that helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

# change names appropriately
PURCHASE_ORDER = 'Purchase Order'
DELIVERY_DATE = 'Delivery Date'
DESIRED_DATE = 'Desired Date'
DELAYED_DAYS = 'Delayed Days'

df = pd.read_csv('otd.csv', index_col=PURCHASE_ORDER)
```

-

```
>> df
                  Delivery Date Desired Date
Purchase Order
001               2014-12-31   2014-12-31
002               2014-12-31   2014-12-31
003               2015-01-05   2015-01-05
004               2015-01-05   2015-01-05
005               2015-02-12   2015-02-11
006               2016-02-13   2016-02-11
```

The last two deliveries are late.

```
df[DELIVERY_DATE] = pd.to_datetime(df[DELIVERY_DATE])
df[DESIRED_DATE] = pd.to_datetime(df[DESIRED_DATE])
df[DELAYED_DAYS] = df[DELIVERY_DATE] - df[DESIRED_DATE]
late_threshold = pd.Timedelta(days=0)
late_deliveries = df[DELAYED_DAYS] > late_threshold
```

-

```
>> df[late_deliveries].drop([DELIVERY_DATE, DESIRED_DATE], axis=1)

                     Delayed Days
Purchase Order             
005                  1 days
006                  2 days
```

Comment: @HarisKhaliq is this the output you are expecting.

Comment: yes it is! I guess I am a little confused by the "fake" data in the categories "Purchase Order", "Delivery Date" and "Desired Date", because I cannot simply put the data into variable like that, this file has over 10000 lines

Comment: @HarisKhaliq, I changed it to simulate reading from a csv file. Change the key names to what you have in your csv file.

Comment: Hi, so I noticed in my terminal, that every row still printed, even the deliveries on time or early. Any idea on why this is happening. Have been trying to figure it out

Comment: Are you sure you are using `df[late_deliveries]`.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you want it to be part of the calculate() function so you can run the function on other stuff. Maybe try doing something like this instead:

```
data = {}
data['ordernum'] = 'ordernum'
data['delayed_days'] = 'diff2'

return data
```

So it's basically returning a python dictionary(json) each time you loop it on a row of your dataframe.

Here is the code that I played with:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
import datetime


def calculate(row):   
    Deliveryvalue = row['delivery']
    Desiredvalue = row['desired']

    date_format = '%m/%d/%Y'

    date1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(Deliveryvalue, date_format)
    date2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(Desiredvalue, date_format)

    diff= date1 - date2
    diff2 = diff.days

    data = {}
    data['ordernum'] = row['order']
    data['delayed_days'] = diff2

    return data

file = pd.read_csv('otd.csv')

l = []

for index, row in file.iterrows():
    data = calculate(row)
    l.append(data)

print(l)
```

I changed bit of how the function works, so now it's running through the rows of dataframe instead. Amd if I'm interpreting your question correct, this should be the solution.

Output:

```
{'ordernum': 1, 'delayed_days': 0}
{'ordernum': 2, 'delayed_days': 0}
{'ordernum': 3, 'delayed_days': 0}
{'ordernum': 4, 'delayed_days': 0}
{'ordernum': 5, 'delayed_days': 0}
```

Comment: Yes that gave me accurate results, however ideally I am looking for a way for the results to be printed in a clean manner where I can display ( the sales team and production team looks at this data and I have a feeling, they'll have a hard time reading this) But this was good thank you!

Comment: @HarisKhaliq you should play with the part where it prints the list to achieve that. I'm sure that JSON is as clean as it can get for the data itself.

Answer (score 2):

I took a different approach and zipped your columns up, then compared them.
Sorry the headers look wonky, I couldn't see the whole thing. I added 2 rows to your csv file to include late deliveries. These orders are:

```
Purchase order number    Delivery Date    Source Desired Deliv
17                       2/10/2018        2/5/2018
18                       7/16/2017        7/14/2018
```

see below:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import csv

df = pd.read_csv('./Desktop/dummy.csv')
late_items = []
date_format = '%m/%d/%Y'

for x,y,z in zip(df['Purchase order number'], df['Delivery Date'], df['Source desired delive']):
    actual_deliv_date = datetime.strptime(y, date_format)       
    supposed_deliv_date = datetime.strptime(z, date_format)    
    diff_deliv_date = supposed_deliv_date - actual_deliv_date
    if diff_deliv_date < timedelta(0):
        late_items.append([x, diff_deliv_date]) 
print(late_items)
```

output:

```
[[17, datetime.timedelta(-5)], [18, datetime.timedelta(-2)]]
```

Or do it this way to just add the 'Diff Delivery Date' column to your original df:

```
diff_delivery_date = []
date_format = '%m/%d/%Y'
for x,y,z in zip(df['Purchase order number'], df['Delivery Date'], df['Source desired delive']):
    actual_deliv_date = datetime.strptime(y, date_format)
    supposed_deliv_date = datetime.strptime(z, date_format)
    diff_deliv_date = supposed_deliv_date - actual_deliv_date
    diff_delivery_date.append(diff_deliv_date)

df['Diff Deliv Date'] = diff_delivery_date
df.loc[df['Diff Deliv Date'] < timedelta(0)] # To get only those values less than 0 for late deliveries.
#df option to output whole df with on time and late deliveries.
```

output:

```
    Purchase order number Delivery Date Source desired delive Diff Deliv Date

5                     17     2/10/2018              2/5/2018         -5 days
6                     18     7/16/2017             7/14/2017         -2 days
```

Comment: Hi, yes the output is coming out how you specified, however how do I have the output look like that very first block of code you have ( with purchase order number 17 and 18)

Comment: would you like the output to come out looking like a dataframe with 2 columns:
`Purchase order number       Diff_deliv_date` with the corresponding numbers underneath? This is just a list output.

Comment: Yes a dataframes with those columns, except beside underneath, side-by side so that the purchase order number is lined up with Diff_deliv_date, similar to how your first block of code looks

Comment: Yup, this is what I was looking for! Thank you

Comment: What happened? Maybe I can help with the fix you are looking for.

Comment: Hi, this example did not address only filtering purchase order numbers that are late, so I thought the other answer someone gave more accurately depicted that. I would appreciate if you would be able to help me with this issue, as the other answer does not fully work as well. Thank you!

Comment: @HarisKhaliq See the updated code, this filters your df for only those orders that are late, returning the whole line.